# Conseguir datos de una tabla MySQL específica con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, get

Estoy tratando de que el código de abajo me devuelva los datos dependiendo el steamid del usuario de mi página. Una base de datos es de la página (la que se muestra debajo) y la otra base de datos que no se muestra, es la de los datos que quiero mostrar. A la hora de poner este código, no me devuelve ningún dato, pero si yo por ejemplo, en donde dice $steamid en $sql, pusiera: steam:1100001323364b7, me devuelve todos los datos. Ya no se que hacer, son horas de quemarme la cabeza con este código y no encontrarle solución.

````
$servers = "localhost";
$users = "x";
$passs = "x";
$databases = "x";

$nombrepags = $_SESSION['username'];

$conns = mysqli_connect($servers, $users, $passs, $databases);
   
   if(! $conns ) {
      die('No se puede conectar: ' . mysql_error());
   }

        $sqls="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$nombrepags'";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conns,$sqls);
        $steamid = $resultado['steamid'];

        $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE identifier='$steamid'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         ?>
         <ul>
         <center><h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 0.02em;"><a style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: red; letter-spacing: 0.02em;">Documento:</a> <?php echo $mostrar['permid'] ?></h2></center>
        <center><h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 0.02em;"><a style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: red; letter-spacing: 0.02em;">Nombre:</a> <?php echo $mostrar['firstname'] ?></h2></center>  </ul>
        <center><h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 0.02em;"><a style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: red; letter-spacing: 0.02em;">Apellido:</a> <?php echo $mostrar['lastname'] ?></h2></center>  </ul>
        <center><h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 0.02em;"><a style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: red; letter-spacing: 0.02em;">Nacimiento:</a> <?php echo $mostrar['dateofbirth'] ?></h2></center>  </ul>
        <center><h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 0.02em;"><a style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: red; letter-spacing: 0.02em;">Altura:</a> <?php echo $mostrar['height'] ?></h2></center>  </ul>
        <center><h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 0.02em;"><a style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: red; letter-spacing: 0.02em;">Género:</a> <?php echo $mostrar['sex'] ?></h2></center>  </ul>
        <center><h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 0.02em;"><a style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: red; letter-spacing: 0.02em;">Celular:</a> <?php echo $mostrar['phone_number'] ?></h2></center>  </ul>
        <!-- <center><h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 0.02em;"><a style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: red; letter-spacing: 0.02em;">Rango VIP:</a> Muy pronto...</h2></center>  </ul> -->
        <center><h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 0.02em;"><a style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: red; letter-spacing: 0.02em;">Dinero en mano:</a> $<?php echo $mostrar['money'] ?></h2></center>  </ul>
        <center><h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 0.02em;"><a style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: red; letter-spacing: 0.02em;">Dinero en banco:</a> $<?php echo $mostrar['bank'] ?></h2></center>  </ul>
<!--         <center><h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 0.02em;"><a style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: red; letter-spacing: 0.02em;">Warns:</a> Muy pronto...</h2></center>  </ul>
        <center><h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 0.02em;"><a style="font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: red; letter-spacing: 0.02em;">Baneos:</a> Muy pronto...</h2></center>  </ul> -->
    <?php 
    }
     ?>```
````

Comment: Chequea que **$nombrepags** en tu base de datos no tenga registros duplicados, o que no te devuelva valores nulos o vacíos; en tu código has un echo $sqls después de la creación de la consulta, para que veas que estas enviando y el resultado ejecutalo directo en mysql para que veas que te retorna.

Comment: ¿Te referís a que devuelve todos los datos de todas las filas o todos los datos de la fila que corresponde a ese id?

Comment: En la primer consulta pusiste `$conns` en la segunda `$conn`, una `s` de diferencia.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede con tu código es que no estas extrayendo el resultado de la primera consulta.

Lo que pasa es que `mysqli_query` entrega un objeto `mysqli_result` el cual te permite ejecutar otras funciones para el manejo del resultado de la consulta, pero no los datos directamente. Aquí hay un enlace que los describe [mysqli-result](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php)

A todo esto para poder ejecutar la segunda consulta, primero tienes que extraer el dato de la primera por lo que puedes resolverlo de la siguiente forma:

```
    $sqls="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$nombrepags'";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conns,$sqls);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)
    $steamid = $fila['steamid'];
```

Eso te permitirá sacar la primera fila de resultado y extraer el dato del steamid